# Order of execution of fields and set/get in C#?

Tags: c#

I am confused about the order of execution in C# regarding the setting of fields and set/get properties. Why is the value in Test2 not set when the constructor gets called while the value in Test is?

When an instance of a class is created is there some type of hidden/default "constructor" that sets the fields but does not call the setter of properties?

Does the setter get automatically called after the constructor or do I explicitly have to call it?

And finally is there good reasoning for this order of execution?

**OUTPUT:**

Test: 5
Test2: 0

```
using System.IO;
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Test test = new Test();
        Test2 test2 = new Test2();
    }
}

class Test
{
    private int x = 5;
    public Test(){
        Console.WriteLine("Test: " + x);
    }
}

class Test2
{
    private int _x;
    private int x{
        get
        {
            return _x;
        }
        set
        {
            _x = 5;
        }
    }
    public Test2(){
        Console.WriteLine("Test2: " + x);
    }
}
```

Comment: What does this have to do with ASP.NET?

Comment: Theres no order of execution going on, you just simply never call the setter on your property only the getter.

Comment: setter is used when you set something to the variable.

Answer (score 8):

> When an instance of a class is created is there some type of hidden/default "constructor" that sets the fields but does not call the setter of properties?

Why would it call the property setters? What would it call them *with*? (Your property setter doesn't use `value`, which it normally would...)

It's not a matter of there being a hidden constructor - it's just that field initializers are executed prior to the base class constructor being called. Property setters are *not* implicitly called.

From section 10.11.2 of the C# 5 spec:

> When an instance constructor has no constructor initializer, or it has a constructor initializer of the form `base(...)`, that constructor implicitly performs the initializations specified by the *variable-initializers* of the instance fields declared in its class.

Note that as of C# 6, you can have automatically implemented properties with default values too:

```
public int Foo { get; set; } = 10;
```

That just means the backing field will be initialized with the value of `10` as a normal field would.

Answer (score 0):

pmaj,

All you need to do is initialize the backing field in test2() the same way you define the field in test().  So you might have the following:

```
class Test2
{
private int _x = -1; // The default value is -1
private int x{
    get
    {
        return _x; // return whatever is in _x
    }
    set
    {
        _x = 5; // Change _x to 5 (or whatever is in value)
    }
}
public Test2(){
    Console.WriteLine("Test2: " + x); // should show -1
    Test2.x = 8;
    Console.WriteLine("Test2: " + x); // should show 8
}
}
```